# Present New ViewController programmatically [Swift 3]

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

What I am trying to do is present a new view controller programmatically with Swift 3 with an animated fade-out then fade-in and a pop-up then pop-down depending on what view controllers the user enters. This is so my app feels more modern and less old and blocky.

Here is the current method I am using for presenting a new view controller. It works, but it is rather abrupt and robotic:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let ExampleVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleVC")
//ExampleVC standing for ExampleViewController 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ExampleVC, animated: false)
```

here is a method for animating UIViews but it doesnt work with UIViewControllers

```
func popIn(yourView : UIView) {

        yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.01, y: 0.01)
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.calculationModeDiscrete, animations: {
            yourView.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
        self.view.addSubview(yourView)
    }
```

i need something similar to this but for a UIViewController

**UPDATE**

here is what you would use to to present a new viewcontroller in a cool way to make your app more modern

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Example") //<<< make sure you enter in your storyboard ID here or you will crash your app
    VC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve //you can change this to do different animations
    VC.view.layer.speed = 0.1 //adjust this to animate at different speeds
    self.navigationController?.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if you have any questions comment them so i can help you guys out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var ivc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ExampleVC")
ivc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
ivc.view.layer.speed = 0.1
self.present(ivc, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
```

Check this code for animation to view controller

Comment: that looks odd though and i dont like it at all (P.S. check my code above for a function that presents CollectionView Cells really cool like

Comment: ok my code above presents a UIView in a pop-up (it scales up from a really small size to a set size) style from the center of the screen i often use this to present data for other things but it doesnt work for UIViewControllers only UIView

Comment: dude that sounds cool ill try it but is there any way to slow it down?

Comment: ivc.view.layer.speed = 0.1  try this for changing speed.
Hope it works

Comment: if you are happy with my answer, please up vote it as well !!
Thanks

Comment: dude you helped me exactly with what i needed im going to mark it as correct